# PiZeroW IPV4 no longer available

Tags: wifi

I powered down my PiZeroW for 24hours, on restarting it I cant SSH in because it isnt connecting to my wifi.  ifconfig shows an ipv6 address, but no ipv4 address.

I changed nothing recently, the Pizero is on Raspbian Jesslie Lite.

This text comes up in red in dmesg, after bcmfmac:

> brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version API:12.2 data 7.11.15 compiler 1.24.2 CLM import 1.24.1 creation 2014-05-26 10:53:55 Inc data 9.10.41 Inc compiler 1.29.4 Inc CLM import 1.36.3 creation 2017-08-07 00:37:47

Comment: I put the PiZero SD card into my Pi3b and it has IPV4 access and I can SSH in, is this a hardware failure on the PiZero, is there a method to troubleshoot it?

Comment: `dmesg` ... and check the various log files in `/var/log`

Comment: There is some red text after brcmfmac in dmesg, I dont know what it means though.  Restarted Pi3 and it seems to be the same, any idea what I might be looking for?

Comment: red text is usually bad - now, I've been told not to use my super powers on earth so I don't attract attention, so, rather than reading your mind, can you actually post the error message, not just its colour ...

Comment: Id love to, but I cant cut & paste it because its only visible in the session when Im connected to HDMI, I will have to write it down and try and transcribe faithfully

Comment: copy the message to a file (`sudo dmesg > /boot/blah.txt`) ... take the card out and put it in a PC/Mac/Whatever ... et voila ... no need for "pen" and "paper" :p

Comment: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version API:12.2 data 7.11.15 compiler 1.24.2 CLM import 1.24.1 creation 2014-05-26 10:53:55 Inc data 9.10.41 Inc compiler 1.29.4 Inc CLM import 1.36.3 creation 2017-08-07 00:37:47

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the message there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a hardware failure.  There is a little connector at the bottom of the v-shaped wireless antenna.  It's very hard to see but it looks to have come loose.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.